# Latex \newcommand in kramdown

Tags: github, latex, jekyll, kramdown

I understand that cramdown does not support \newcommand type macros. 
Is there a workaround that does not involve Pandoc, so that it could be used with Jekyll in a GitHub blog?

This would be the input markdown:

```
---
layout: post
---

\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}

This is a test $$\a$$.
```

The output should be a Jekyll blog, with mathematical notation, like [this](https://johnros.github.io/building-blocks-of-machine-learning/).

Comment: Can you explain a little more. What are your input and expected output ?

Comment: I want to write a post, to be parsed by Jekyll, that has mathematical equations with latex, using some \newcommands. The input is thus a markdown (kramdown) page, and the output is a Jekyll website.

Comment: @JohnRos couldnt you just use http://mathjax.org ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm dumb and I still didn't see you input and desired output.

Comment: @StevenPenny: the latest versions of kramdown will recognize latex correctly, and the output can indeed be viewed with mathjax. A \newcommand however, is parsed by kramdown as plain text.

Comment: @DavidJacquel: i edited the question trying to demonstrate the input and output.

Comment: As @StevenPenny says use mathjax http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/faq.html#does-mathjax-support-tex-macros

Comment: What about `\def\a{\alpha}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two questions here — first, can one define commands in kramdown similar to LaTeX's `\newcommand` syntax, and second, can kramdown support mathematics.

Regarding the first issue, kramdown itself doesn't support that syntax or anything like it that I'm aware of, [and probably isn't going to in the future](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/12), so you can't define non-math kramdown commands. You'd need to use a language that's focused on completeness rather than ease and simplicity, like LaTeX, to get features like that.

For math, though, MathJax (the parser kramdown uses) does parse `\newcommand`: just go ahead and use it in the first code block. So for example,

```
$$\newcommand{\a}{\alpha} \a{}/2 $$
```

yields the expected fraction with the expected Computer Modern italic Greek alpha, and you'll also be able to use `\a` in every subsequent code block. You can also have a code block at the beginning of your document that contains all of your `\newcommand` definitions if you don't want them to be interspersed in random code blocks throughout your document.

Regarding the second issue, as I guess is obvious at this point, kramdown does handle math using similar notation to LaTeX:

```
Here is a paragraph with some inline math, $$ \pi{}/2 $$, followed by
some text and a math block.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi} $$
```

This yields:

```
<p>Here is a paragraph with some inline math, <script
type="math/tex">\pi{}/2</script>, followed by some text and a math 
block.</p>

<script type="math/tex; mode=display">\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}
dx = \sqrt{\pi}</script>
```

If that isn't successfully rendering for you on your site, don't forget to [include the MathJax library](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#using-the-mathjax-content-delivery-network-cdn) in the `<head>` of your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.